# A,B,C, and D are sets. Prove if A∪B⊆C∪D, A∩B=∅, and C⊆A, then B⊆D.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am probably 100% wrong with my approach, but this is what I have so far.

A,B,C, and D are sets.

Assume A∪B⊆C∪D, A∩B=∅, and C⊆A.
Let x∈A∪B. By the def of subset, if x∈A V x∈B, then x∈C V x∈D.
Recall that C⊆A. Using the def of subset, if x∈C then x∈A.
Therefore, if x∈A V x∈B, then x∈A V x∈D.
This implies that if x∈B, then x∈D.
This can be rewritten as B⊆D, using the def of subset.
Thus, if A∪B⊆C∪D, A∩B=∅, and C⊆A, then B⊆D.

That's what I have so far. However, I don't know where A∩B=∅ comes into play in the proof.

Comment: Try think if $A \cap B \not = \emptyset$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume A,B,C,D are sets.

Suppose that A $\cup$ B$\subseteq$ C$\cup$D, A$\cap$B=$\emptyset$, and C$\subseteq$A.

Then C$\cup$D $\subseteq$ A$\cup$D. Let x $\in$ B. Therefore x $\in$ A $\cup$B, so x$\in$ A$\cup$D.  As A$\cap$B=$\emptyset$, x $\notin$A. Since x$\in$ A$\cup$D, but x $\notin$A, x must be an element of D. This implies that B $\subseteq$ D, as desired

Comment: @BDYG improved this a little.

Answer (score 1):

I would sooner focus on the goal of showing $B\subseteq D$ by letting $x\in B$ which by $A\cap B=\emptyset$ implies $x\not\in A$ which by $C\subseteq A$ implies $x\not\in C$.  But since $x\in A\cup B\subseteq C\cup D$ then $x\in D$.

That is, we have seen that whenever $x\in B$ then $x\in D$.  But that's the definition of $B\subseteq D$.

Comment: I think that's better